# How to reference the clicked element within a function that is called by the handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
    someFunction();
});

function someFunction() {
    var btnID = $(".btn").attr("data-index"); // This selector should reference the button that was clicked
    console.log(btnID);
}
```

I want the selector inside `someFunction()` to reference the exact button that was clicked, not just the first element in the DOM with the class `.btn`.

Is there a way to do this without giving all buttons unique IDs?

Comment: Maybe `function someFunction() { btnID = this.attr("data-index"); console.log(btnID); }`  is what you seek? `this` being the clicked element.

Answer (score 0):

You can give same class and different id's for the buttons.

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
    someFunction();
});

function someFunction() {
     $(".btn").each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr("id")+" value:"+$(this).val());
    
    })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="btn" id="btn1" value="1">
<input type="button"class="btn" id="btn2" value="2">
<input type="button" class="btn" id="btn3" value="3">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not separate the callback from the event handler.

Instead, just incorporate the callback into the handler directly. Then you can reference the element using the 'this' keyword

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
     var btnID = $(this).data("index");
     console.log(btnID);
 });
```

Also, it's worth noting that when you are using a 'data' attribute, you can reference it using `$(el).data('attrName')`